# How to print between the Details Section or Subreport in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a CR with 2 different letters. One letter is in the Details Section and the other letter is in a Subreport.

Basically, if the table.field = 1,2,3 or 9 then I want to print the Subreport. If the table.field <> 1,2,3 or 9 then I want to print the Details Section.

I know that I would need to suppress one over the other but I don't know the easiest way to do this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you checking the data? Is it a runtime or any static checking inside report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is next.

Your report contains :

1. subreport which shows if value of field is 1,2,3 or 9
2. detail section shows if value of field is <> 1,2,3 or 9

Go to section expert, detail section and under "supress" write formula

[image]

```
if ({table.field} = 1 or {table.field} = 2 or {table.field} = 3 or {table.field} = 9) = false then false
else true
```

Right click on subreport and unders "supress" triger write formula.
[image]

Formula for subreport is

```
if {table.field} = 1 or {table.field} = 2 or {table.field} = 3 or {table.field} = 9 then false
else true
```

And this should do the trick. I'm sure there is other ways to solve this situation, but this is how i do it.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: KuKeC - thank you for your help! You pointed me in the right direction. After a few tweaks, the code you suggested definitely helped. I did however have to put all of the letters in separate detail sections. The suppression was not working for me with the subreport - not really sure how or why but moved on from it.

Thanks again!

Comment: @CRrptWriter73 Glad it helped you :)